# Why is PHP still working under apache2 after I have removed both mpm-prefork and mpm-worker !

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have uninstalled both mpm-prefork and mpm-worker from my apache2 installation on ubuntu linux, but PHP pages are still being server !

Why is this happening ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "uninstalled" the mpms? All the Apache2 packages I've dealt with have had the prefork/worker MPM compiled into the executable. Also, the prefork/worker MPMs have to do with how Apache handles incoming requests and nothing specifically to do with PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you restarted Apache? If not, the Apache process will still have the modules loaded in memory.

EDIT:
It's pretty unlikely that Ubuntu will let you install Apache without any MPM (because otherwise Apache wouldn't be able to do anything). I suspect that it's probably automatically (re)installed one of those MPMs or (less likely) installed one of the other ones.

If you don't mind me asking, what is it that you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Yups. restated it and the OS too. Its still working !

Comment: Yes you're right, i checked the list of installed packages and apache2-mpm-itk was installed, when I tried uninstalling that, it uninstalled it and installed mpm-worker automatically :)

Comment: well im new to linux and apache and php, so was just playing around and I saw this strange behaviour and due to lack of knowledge on how to find stuff in linux I asked here.

Comment: Ok, well, fair enough. I think we've both learned something here.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

mpm-prefork and mpm-worker are unrelated to PHP. You must have at least one worker installed, otherwise Apache can't serve even static content. The package that provides mod_php is libapache2-mod-php5. There are other packages for configuring Apache to access PHP via FastCGI.